# Размерность структуры данных

Tags: c++

Что такое размерность структуры данных?

У меня есть такая структура данных как очередь (реализованная списком), объекты в ней хранятся как ссылки, но я вот не пойму, что значит "размерность моей структуры данных - дин. массив". Пролейте мне на это свет, пожалуйста, а то я запутался. Я понимаю так: то есть придется реализовать очередь, ссылающуюся на объекты, которые в свою очередь будут находиться в дин. массиве. И указатели `head` и `tail` будут ссылаться на начало и конец массива соответственно. Правильно ли я понимаю?

Comment: Трудно что-то сказать по словам, вырванным из контекста. Приведете более полное описание, где эти слова присутствуют.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Вам покажется странным, но так задание и сформулировано, поэтому я сюда и написал, наверное, препод намудрил.

Comment: Приведите полную формулировка задания, а не пересказывайте ее своими словами.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow
Структура данных: циклическая очередь.
   Способ хранения объектов: ссылки на объекты.  
   Размерность структуры данных: динамический массив.  
   Операция: включение в конец очереди.  
   Операция: исключение из очереди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходить из этого описания, которое вы дали в комментарии к своему вопросу

> Структура данных: циклическая очередь. Способ хранения объектов:
>   ссылки на объекты. Размерность структуры данных: динамический массив.
>   Операция: включение в конец очереди. Операция: исключение из очереди

то выражение

> "Размерность структуры данных: динамический массив"

выглядит как оговорка, которая не имеет смысла.

Скорей всего имелось в виду, что размерность очереди, под которой понимается максимальное количество элементов, которые могут быть в очереди, определяется размерностью (или размером) динамически создаваемого массива.

То есть в соответствующем классе, описывающим очередь, вам следует определить конструктор, который будет иметь параметр, задающий максимальное количество элементов в очереди, и  значение этого параметра будет использовано в качестве размерности динамического массива, который будет хранить элементы очереди.

Comment: А еще вопрос, по заданию способ хранения объектов: ссылки на объекты, то есть мне нужно будет создать массив указателей?

Comment: @zof Да, по всей видимости вам нужно создать массив указателей на тип объектов, которые будут храниться в очереди.

Comment: @zof,  я эту часть описания (о динамическом массиве) понимаю так -- размерность (правильно было бы сказать **размер**) (количество элементов очереди) **не ограничена** - используйте динамический массив с ссылками на элементы очереди.

Comment: @avp Возможно, что вы правы. Но, с другой стороны, как такая очередь может быть циклической, если она не ограничена?:)

Answer (score 1):

Размерность бывает у массивов. Это понятие означает, сколько индексов есть у каждого элемента.

Вот массив размерности 1:

```
int x[10];
```

Вот массив размерности 2 (иногда такие массивы называют матрицами):

```
int x[10][10];
```

Вот массив размерности 3:

```
int x[10][10][10];
```

У структуры данных размерность определена только в том случае, когда она похожа на массив. Т.е. хранит данные, сопоставленные с некоторым индексом.

В случае очереди обратиться можно только к одному элементу - первому. Поэтому размерность очереди "снаружи" - ноль. С другой стороны, "внутри" очередь - это просто список, а у простого списка размерность 1.

Comment: М.б. имеется в виду "размер"? `YourClass a; sizeof(a);`

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ...

Comment: @andy.37: Размер и размерность имеют столько же общего, как кот и котангенс.

Comment: @VladD, на самом деле больше. Если брать вектор в понимании программистов (динамический массив), то у него есть размер. Если же взять ту же самую структуру, но рассмотреть ее в исконно-математическим смысле - то количество координат вектора "внезапно" становится его размерностью :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, хм. Если у кота измерить угол между усами, то там тоже появляется котангенс :) Но да, вы правы, связь в определённом смысле есть.